# How can I count the line and compare to get result as PASS

Tags: robotframework

Here's my Robot code

```
cx_Oracle    ${DB_CONNECT_STRING}

@{queryResults1}=   Query  Select * from QA_USER.SealTest_Security_A
Log  ${queryResults1}
@{queryResults2}=   Query  Select * from QA_USER.SealTest_Security_B
Log  ${queryResults2}

${cnt1}=  get line count  ${queryResults1}
${cnt2}=  get line count  ${queryResults2}

should be equal as integers    ${cnt1}     ${cnt2}


Disconnect From Database
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [Get length](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Length) keyword from the built-in library?

Comment: Have you got an example of what's in the ${queryResults} variables? For example, if it's string where "\n" represents new line you can easily count occurrences of this string. Then you should be able to use something like:

Should Be Equal As Integers    ${queryResults1.count("\n")}    ${queryResults2.count("\n")}